# Writing a new jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

```
<table class="data" border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        </tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>

        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

While iterating through each `tr` element, check whether the given `<tr>` element has a checked checkbox, if so add the new class. If not, remove it.

```
jQuery.fn.deleteMark = function() {

   this.each(function() {
        alert( $('input:checkbox',this) );
        if ($('checkbox',this).is(':checked')){
            $(this).addClass("delemarked");
        }
        else{
            $(this).removeClass("delemarked");
        }
   })
};
```

Now I want to add a class to each `tr` that is checked:

```
function refresh(){
    $('.data tbody tr').each(function() {
        $(this).deleteMark();
    });        
}
```

Sadly this doesn't work for me. I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `checkbox`, you need `:checkbox` for a selector, as there are no `<checkbox>` elements, like this:

```
$(':checkbox',this)
```

Though you can shorten your overall approach with `.toggleClass("className", bool)`, like this:

```
jQuery.fn.deleteMark = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("delemarked", $(this).find(":checkbox:checked").length > 0);
  });
};
```

Also, there's no need for the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) calling your plugin, just this will do:

```
$('.data tbody tr').deleteMark();
```

[You can test all of the change above here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/MGAbg/).

Answer (score 1):

You example has this:  `$('checkbox',this)`

The reason it isn't working is that you're referencing `checkbox` as if it were an element name, which it isn't.

Instead, you need to be using `[type=checkbox]` or just `:checkbox` (these two do exactly the same thing)

So your code would look like this:

```
if ($('[type=checkbox]',this).is(':checked'))
```

or this:

```
if ($(':checkbox',this).is(':checked'))
```

See [the checkbox selector JQuery manual page](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) for more info.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a plugin for that:

```
$('.data tbody tr:has(:checkbox:checked)').addClass("delemarked");
$('.data tbody tr:has(:checkbox:not(:checked))').removeClass("delemarked");
```

or (depending on your taste)

```
$('.data tbody tr:has(:checkbox)').removeClass("delemarked").has(':checkbox:checked').addClass('delemarked');
```